# iOS – Download Facebook data in background with GCD

Tags: objective-c, delegates, grand-central-dispatch

My situation is that every time when my app becomes active I need to sync some data from Facebook. This sync should be made in the background and should not lock the GUI (thus it should not run on the main queue).

So in my `- applicationDidBecomeActive:` method I have this code:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(0,0), ^{

    [[FacebookHelper sharedInstance] syncData];
});
```

FacebookHelper is a singleton class that takes care of all Facebook handling. In the FacebookHelper class I have implemented the Facebook delegate methods. But for some reason when I run the above code the Facebook delegate method `- request:didLoad:` (when the Facebook data is finished downloading) is never called. Although if I run the same code with `dispatch_sync` it will finish (but then the GUI will be blocked).

Edit: Facebook SDK v2

Comment: Is it possible your background queue is deadlocked? Since you're on a queue your UI would continue to function, but perhaps your background task cannot make any forward progress.

Comment: Chances are your background thread is completing before any callback is attempted - if so you'd need to do this work in a runloop, rather than just a thread.  Obviously I don't know your exact example, but this is a standard problem with running things like network transfers on background queues.

Answer (score 0):

Actually after analyzing the code I noticed it was an internal processing method that was done  in the `- request:didLoad:` delegate method. So I just put that internal processing method inside a dispatch_async block and it performed nicely in the background.

Thanks for your help!